# Can the Negation of a Conditional Implying the First Atomic Proposition Get Proven in Around 50 Steps?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages, formal-proofs, formal-systems

The following uses Polish notation with the following definition for meaningful expressions.

1. All lower case letters are meaningful expressions.
2. If $\alpha$ is a meaningful expression, then so is N$\alpha$.
3. If $\alpha$ is a meaningful expression, if $\beta$ is a meaningful expression also, then C$\alpha$$\beta$ is a meaningful expression.

The axioms are

Ax1 CxCyx

Ax2 CCxCyzCCxyCxz

Ax3 CCNxNyCyx

The rules of inference are uniform substitution for any thesis of the system and C-detachment, from $\vdash$C$\alpha$$\beta$, from $\vdash$$\alpha$ also, we may infer $\vdash$$\beta$.

Can CNCxyx get proven in around 50 steps?

Comment: My assistant OTTER has found some decent candidates to write shortish proofs, possibly near 50 lines of the theorem schema CNCxyx. In OTTER's system what I have, have length 23, level 11; length 21, level 12; and one of length 20, level 13, all of which might help. I'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the axioms as steps in the proof, the following consists of a less than 50 step which indicates an answer of yes.

```
                                                     Expansion Number

                       1 CxCyx   

                       2 CCxCyzCCxyCxz 

                       3 CCNxNyCyx 

1/CxCyx, y/z           4 CCxCyxCzCxCyx

4 * C1-5               5 CzCxCyx                            2 

1 x/CCNxNyCyx, y/z     6 CCCNxNyCyxCzCCNxNyCyx

6 * C3-7               7 CzCCNxNyCyx                        2

2 x/z, y/x, z/Cyx      8 CCzCxCyxCCzxCzCyx

8 * C5-9               9 CCzxCzCyx                          2

2 x/z, y/CNxNy, z/Cyx  10 CCzCCNxNyCyxCCzCNxNyCzCyx          

10 * C7-11             11 CCzCNxNyCzCyx                      2

11 z/Ny                12 CCNyCNxNyCNyCyx                    

1 x/Ny, y/Nx           13 CNyCNxNy

12 * C13-14            14 CNyCyx                             3

9 z/Ny, x/Cyx, y/z     15 CCNyCyxCNyCzCyx

15 * C14-16            16 CNyCzCyx                           2

2 x/Ny, z/x            17 CCNyCyxCCNyyCNyx

17 * C14-18            18 CCNyyCNyx                          2

11 z/CNyy, x/y, y/x    19 CCCNyyCNyNxCCNyyCxy

18 x/Nx                20 CCNyyCNyNx 

19 * C20-21            21 CCNyyCxy                           3

1 x/CCNyyCNyx, y/z     22 CCCNyyCNyxCzCCNyyCNyx

22 * C18-23            23 CzCCNyyCNyx                        2

2 x/CNyy, y/x, z/y     24 CCCNyyCxyCCCNyyxCCNyyy

24 * C21               25 CCCNyyxCCNyyy                      2

2 x/z, y/CNyy, z/CNyx  26 CCzCCNyyCNyxCCzCNyyCzCNyx

26 * 23-27             27 CCzCNyyCzCNyx                      2

25 x/Cxy               28 CCCNyyCxyCCNyyy

28 * C21-29            29 CCNyyy                             2

27 z/Ny, y/Cyx, x/z    30 CCNyCNCyxCyxCNyCNCyxz

16 z/NCyx              31 CNyCNCyxCyx

30 * C31-32            32 CNyCNCyxz                          3

1 x/CCNyyy, y/x        33 CCCNyyyCxCCNyyy

33 * C29-34            34 CxCCNyyy                           2

2 x/Ny, y/NCyx         35 CCNyCNCyxzCCNyNCyxCNyz

35 * C32-36            36 CCNyNCyxCNyz                       2

2 y/CNyy, z/y          37 CCxCCNyyyCCxCNyyCxy

37 * C34-38            38 CCxCNyyCxy                         2

9 z/CxCNyy, x/Cxy, y/z 39 CCCxCNyyCxyCCxCNyyCzCxy

39 * C38-40            40 CCxCNyyCzCxy                       2

40 x/CNyNCyx           41 CCCNyNCyxCNyyCzCCNyNCyxy 

36 z/y                 42 CCNyNCyxCNyy

41 * C42-43            43 CzCCNyNCyxy                        3

2 x/z, y/CNyNCyx, z/y  44 CCzCCNyNCyxyCCzCNyNCyxCzy

44 * C43-45            45 CCzCNyNCyxCzy                      2

45 z/NCxy, y/x, x/y    46 CCNCxyCNxNCxyCNCxyx

1 x/NCxy, y/NCxy       47 CNCxyCNxNCxy

46 * C47-48            48 CNCxyx                             3
```

I constructed the above proof with the help of this first-order, hyperresolution proof I found with [OTTER](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/otter/) as my assistant.

1 [] -P(C(x,y))| -P(x)|P(y).

2 [] -P(C(N(C(p,N(q))),p)).

3 [] P(C(x,C(y,x))).

4 [] P(C(C(x,C(y,z)),C(C(x,y),C(x,z)))).

5 [] P(C(C(N(x),N(y)),C(y,x))).

6 [hyper,1,3,3] P(C(x,C(y,C(z,y)))).

8 [hyper,1,3,5] P(C(x,C(C(N(y),N(z)),C(z,y)))).

9 [hyper,1,4,6] P(C(C(x,y),C(x,C(z,y)))).

15 [hyper,1,4,8] P(C(C(x,C(N(y),N(z))),C(x,C(z,y)))).

30 [hyper,1,15,3] P(C(N(x),C(x,y))).

67 [hyper,1,9,30] P(C(N(x),C(y,C(x,z)))).

68 [hyper,1,4,30] P(C(C(N(x),x),C(N(x),y))).

136 [hyper,1,15,68] P(C(C(N(x),x),C(y,x))).

138 [hyper,1,3,68] P(C(x,C(C(N(y),y),C(N(y),z)))).

220 [hyper,1,4,136] P(C(C(C(N(x),x),y),C(C(N(x),x),x))).

240 [hyper,1,4,138] P(C(C(x,C(N(y),y)),C(x,C(N(y),z)))).

326 [hyper,1,220,136] P(C(C(N(x),x),x)).

353 [hyper,1,240,67] P(C(N(x),C(N(C(x,y)),z))).

459 [hyper,1,3,326] P(C(x,C(C(N(y),y),y))).

503 [hyper,1,4,353] P(C(C(N(x),N(C(x,y))),C(N(x),z))).

659 [hyper,1,4,459] P(C(C(x,C(N(y),y)),C(x,y))).

902 [hyper,1,9,659] P(C(C(x,C(N(y),y)),C(z,C(x,y)))).

1343 [hyper,1,902,503] P(C(x,C(C(N(y),N(C(y,z))),y))).

1859 [hyper,1,4,1343] P(C(C(x,C(N(y),N(C(y,z)))),C(x,y))).

2803 [hyper,1,1859,3] P(C(N(C(x,y)),x)).

4153 [hyper,2,2803] $F.